# Bind Datapoints in JUnit Theory to a particular variable

Tags: java, junit

I have following theory to test. In the code I want **variable a to be Even and variable b to be odd**

```
@RunWith(Theories.class)
public class TestJunit{
   // add the error
  @DataPoints
  public static Integer[] integersOdd() {
     return new Integer[]{1, 3, 5};
  }

  @DataPoints
  public static Integer[] integersEven() {
    return new Integer[]{2, 4, 6};
 }

   @Theory
   public void testAdd(Integer a , Integer b) {
        ...
   }
}
```

For now I am using assumeTrue and a validation function as in:

```
   public boolean validateInput(Integer a, Integer b){
     Set<Integer> even = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(integersEven()));
     Set<Integer> odd = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(integersOdd()));
     return (even.contains(a) && odd.contains(b));
   }
```

Modified Theory:

```
   @Theory
   public void testAdd(Integer a , Integer b) {
     Assume.assumeTrue(validateInput(a,b));
     System.out.println("a="+a+", b="+b);
     assertTrue(a+b>-1);
   // add any test
   }
```

It is a very dirty way as Java will pick all the combinations and will discard the inputs at **assumeTrue**. What If I have 10 theories with 10 datapoints? Java will try 100 combinations where I wanted only 10!

Is there neat way to do so? May be some annotation to tell JUnit to pick values for variables from which DataPoint?

**Edit:**
Another way I found is to use Test Generators. I am using JUnit-QuickCheck [[Read Here](https://github.com/pholser/junit-quickcheck/)] to generate random data according to the range required by my variables. Then I encapsulate them in a class and pass this object into my theory to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JUnit 4.12 allows for named data points in theories. Here's the [original pull request](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/pull/621), and here are the [release notes for 4.12](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/doc/ReleaseNotes4.12.md) - look for "Added mechanism for matching specific data points".

Comment: Wow! This is an awesome addition. 
By the way I got to thank you for the junit-quickcheck library. I am using it and Its much simple and convenient to use.